# call php function in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call a PHP function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984545/how-to-call-a-php-function-in-javascript)

i have a form to print  to a POS printer. Problem 1 is that i cant print directly, Mybe in google chrome  in kioskmode.. so. i would like to call a function after  the windows be closed from printing. code is like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#printOut').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var w = window.open();
                var printOne = $('.contentToPrint').html();
                var printTwo = $('.termsToPrint').html();
                w.document.write('<html>' + printOne + '<hr />' + printTwo   ) + '</body></html>';

                w.window.print();

                w.document.close();
   I INSERTED HERE>>>   insert();  <<<<<<<<<<< AND  WORKS BUT NOT BY CLOSING THE priter WINDOWS. I dont want to close the BROWSER!  
                return false;

            });
        });
    </script>
```

where can i call the php function insert();

Comment: this should help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984545/how-to-call-a-php-function-in-javascript

Comment: JavaScript is client side. PHP is server side. This is not possible without an ajax call.

Comment: "POS" - point of sale, or piece of s***? " i would like to call a function after the windows be closed from printing" . Can you try to re-word that? Are you saying you want to print after the window (browser) has been closed? Where are you trying to insert() something?  Please edit your question...

Answer (score 0):

You can't *call* a PHP function since it's on the sever and your JavaScript code is on the client. You can navigate to a PHP containing that function or make an AJAX call to that page.

Navigating via Javascript would be:

```
document.location = "yourpage.php"
```

Comment: You should have some JavaScript in the destination page close the window once it loads.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call PHP functions in the classic sense with Javascript. PHP code is run on the server, while Javascript code is executed in the user's browser window. What you can do however is use a technology called [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to send a request back to your server. Using HTTP methods you could initiate a PHP script that returns information back to your Javascript code also over HTTP.

Comment: its works :-) but i dot know where can i put in so that call if the script runs to the end. If i insert on wrong place call every time as i relode the page

Comment: I call like **alert ("<? echo inserPHP(); ?> ");** like this i can start the php function. The only one problem is i want to have a popup windows fro ask to insert and if click OK than iserting if No than just close the windows.