# Triggering a php loop with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I don't need any code for this, just the different steps I'd need in order to do something like this:

Basically:

- The user writes something on a text input field
- When the user finishes typing, it triggers a php loop
- The loop compares what the user wrote to what's on a .csv table
- If what the user typed is identical to anything on the database, it triggers something
- Else, it does nothing

I really can't make my mind to this, could anyone just explain me the steps I'd have to do in order to do it?

Comment: how do you know user finishes typing..?? if you know that point then make an ajax call with the text that user types and compare it on the server side and do what ever you require.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a PHP function in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984545/how-to-call-a-php-function-in-javascript)

Comment: I guess it could work with a _keyup_ function no? I don't know ajax unfortunately

Comment: making an ajax call is much less daunting and much more comprehensible  when working with `jQuery` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  Just google _jquery ajax php example_ and you will have more than enough examples to look over

Answer (score 0):

You can user JQuery library to help you.

First include jquery script in header of your page

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

then add a script to control

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function(){
$( "#target" ).keypress(function() {
        //input length more than 2
        if($("#target").val().length > 2)
        {
            $.post( "handle.php", { searchkey: $("#target").val()})
            .done(function( data ) {
                //Do something to handle your return.
                alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
            });
        }
    });

});

</script>

<input id="target" type="text" value="">
```

Your PHP handle.php here

```
<?php
print_r($_POST["searchkey"]);

?>
```